# UK visitor visa refused (multiple sponsors)

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I helped my mother apply for visitor visa to UK and received a refusal today.

Documents submitted included:

- Mother's - Application letter, 3 year Income Tax return (ITR)(340000:2015-16), Bank statement with sufficient funds, bank passbook, bank balance certificate
- Sister's (sponsor) - Invitation letter, copy of passport, copy of ni, bank statement, visiting card, business related documents
- Father's - Financial supporting letter and NOC letter, 3 yr ITR(400000:2015-16), bank statement, pan card, copy of passport

Total family income (including father & mother) for 2015-16 = 400000+340000 = 740000inr/12 = 61666inr (approx) on which the ECO has given refusal.

Please tell me what to do now?

[image: refusal letter]

Comment: Pretty sure we've got a duplicate to this, just can't find the exact one from a simple search... Hopefully @gayot-fow will be along in a bit to help!

Comment: The problem appears to have been claiming joint income as personal income. If someone else supports an applicant financially, thats fine, but that should be mentioned, not just added to the individual's claimed income.

Comment: we have attacthed the letter from my father stating the same.but in the main application not mentioned.

Comment: There have to be atleast 2 sources which should corroborate the amount claimed as salary. If your bank account says something and tax return says something else, then it is considered insufficient.

Comment: @Gagravarr, indeed I'm grateful for your vote of confidence. This is a very borderline case, but falls on the side of non-duplicate IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

This refusal cites Paragraphs V 4.2 (a) and (c) of the rules. The popular interpretation of this is that they think you intend to overstay and go underground in the UK and inevitably to become reliant on public funds.

They established this by comparing your stated income with other sources and spotting a discrepancy. This was then factored in to your personal circumstances and then combined with the overall risk index for Indian applicants.

You can see that they did not challenge your daughter's capacity for sponsorship, they accepted her sponsorship without question. But having a credible sponsor does not alleviate the applicant's burden of meeting the rules.

Based upon what you wrote, they did not attribute some of the income streams correctly and this caused the discrepancy in the different values.

The actual question you are asking is not clear, but it's safe to assume it is...

> What can I do about this?

There is no path for appeal and judicial reviews of visitor applications seldom, if ever, reach the hearing stage.  What this amalgamates to is there's nothing to be done by way of judicial remedy. A fresh application is called for at a later time.

> Can we clear up their misunderstanding about my sponsorship in a future application?

Yes, but it will be of marginal value. The ECO wrote "...I need to assess **your own** personal and economic circumstances..." Unless those circumstances have changed dramatically, you will enter a tail spin of serial refusals. I would back down from having everyone in your immediate family sponsor you and try it with your own resources. Have your daughter offer accommodation and maintenance in the UK and that's it. If you are not ready to do that, then for heaven's sake do not apply.

> Can we apply again right now?

You can make a fresh application as soon as your passport is returned and you have the necessary photographs.  However, read the above.

---

Note: Despite the **totally**  **awesome** archives on this site for [UK visa refusals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-refusal), I determined that your question is not a duplicate. While we have lots of questions where applicants got refused with the discrepancy method, none of them have the clarity indicated in your refusal notice about multiple sponsors and the double-edged sword that can result.

Comment: i have 3 questions:1-<There is no path for appeal and judicial reviews of visitor applications seldom, if ever, reach the hearing stage. What this amalgamates to is there's nothing to be done.>Can i go for administrial review...........2-< Unless those circumstances have changed dramatically>can you tell some more on it.......3-< I would back down from having everyone in your immediate family sponsor you and try it with your own resources. Have your daughter offer accommodation and maintenance in the UK and that's it.>ie except daughter Husband/anyone frm family doc r not required to support

Comment: No. You asked your question and you got an answer.  It is unfair to the community to linger in comments raising new things because making comments is a gated function. Use the 'Ask Question' button to put your stuff in a new question so that everyone can see it and give an answer.

Comment: first of all thanks for your prompt reply .But it is related to same question and the answer you gave.

Comment: Yes, related but also drifting. And remember that your questions were imputed, not expressed. So you can ask a new question with laser-like focus on a single item.

Comment: Yes ,Submitted.Looking Forward to get a reply.Thanks