# UK visitor visa refused (multiple sponsors) - second part

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I have Three questions :

> There is no path for appeal and judicial reviews of visitor applications seldom, if ever, reach the hearing stage. What this amalgamates to is there's nothing to be done.

1. Can I go for administrative review?

> Unless those circumstances have changed dramatically

2. Can you please tell some more on it?
3. But as you mentioned

   > Based upon what you wrote, they did not attribute some of the income streams correctly and this caused the discrepancy in the different values. There will be possibility to overlook again by the ECO.

and also

> Yes, but it will be of marginal value. The ECO wrote "...I need to assess your own personal and economic circumstances..." Unless those circumstances have changed dramatically, you will enter a tail spin of serial refusals. I would back down from having everyone in your immediate family sponsor you and try it with your own resources. Have your daughter offer accommodation and maintenance in the UK and that's it. If you are not ready to do that, then for heaven's sake do not apply.

i.e. except from the daughter,nor the Husband or anyone from my family would give  the fund supporting documents. Kindly tell me what additional documents are required from my daughter to support?

Answer (score 3):

You left a question at [UK visitor visa refused (multiple sponsors)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73404/uk-visitor-visa-refused-multiple-sponsors) wherein the actual question(s) were imputed from your text rather than expressed directly. Based on the answer you got, you can now raise explicit questions and are taking the opportunity to do so. See this comment: [UK visitor visa refused (multiple sponsors)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73404/uk-visitor-visa-refused-multiple-sponsors#comment159880_73412)

Briefly (and predictably), you were refused on Paragraphs V 4.2 (a) and (c) of the rules because of a very weak application and discrepancies in your income streams. From [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)...

> Sponsored applications are weak to begin with and they do not relieve
>   the applicant of demonstrating ties to the local economy and social
>   landscape. While the money may be there, it is much more difficult for
>   the applicant to make a strong case that they will not overstay or
>   abuse their visa in some other way. Generally, sponsorship should be
>   used only as a last resort and only if the applicant can provide a
>   compellingly strong case.

You are asking how to proceed.

> Can i go for administrative review?

No. This is what happens from reading the net rather than the rules and guidance. Administrative Review is a procedure for economic applicants, like work permits and entrepreneurs.  And the AR regime was overhauled last April making the bulk of forum material obsolete anyway.

> can you please tell some more on it [change of circumstances].

Things like...

- you graduated from university;
- Your circumstances are such that you are now leading an independent
  life without support from your parents;
- You have become married or divorced;
- You received an inheritance;
- And so on.

Those are examples and they are not always applicable to each case.

And by far and away, the *ultimate* change of circumstances is to apply and receive an entry clearance. This acts as a global panacea to almost all UK visa problems.

> There will be possibility to overlook again by the ECO.

The ECO did not 'overlook' something; the income streams were ambiguously identified. Use precision next time and the ECO will know what to attribute to you versus what to attribute to your co-sponsors.

> Kindly tell me what additional documents are required from my daughter
>   to support.

She needs to submit all the documents that you are submitting in order to demonstrate her capacity for sponsorship. In addition she should submit...

- Permission from the landlord (or tenancy agreement giving
  permission); and
- A personal attestation that she will be in the UK for the entire
  duration of your visit.